# Remove default image before image load

Tags: html, image, default

Hey, so I am not looking to do anything along the lines of a pre-loader, I just want to know how to keep the browser from displaying this image:
[image]
Before the image loads.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it all depends on the browser and the speed of the user's connection.

You can always use a javascript preloader to stop an image from displaying until it is fully loaded on the users computer

try this [jquery preloader](http://farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/)

:-D

Comment: How would I do this if I am displaying them through a mysql query, and i do not know the actual dimensions of the image?

Comment: what does it have to do with the dimensions. its all on the client (user's) side. if his internet is slow and you dont have anything to stop the image from displaying before loading, he will see that image

Comment: Ah, all preloaders I have seen require the dimensions of the image for some reason..

Comment: im not sure what preloaders you are talking about. you have to elaborate.

Comment: Javascript pre-loaders, which make you define the actual image src as well. Looking for one that will just pre-load ALL images I guess

Comment: This is great, but it gets at my problem. I wont have the image paths readily available, they will all be generated on the fly by the php, and they all have different filenames. That make sense?

Comment: you dont need 'paths' with jquery. once the don is loaded, you can use `$('img') ` to get all the images on the page. php is on server side and doesnt know what has loaded on the client

Comment: Ok, ill take a futher look into this. Do you know of any that is not jQuery? I am trying to avoid libraries at the moment.

Comment: use javascript, or any client app. php is all on server side.

Comment: I understand that. I assume I will have to use js, I just wasnt sure if you knew any good pre-loaders w/o the use of a library like jquery

Comment: lol look it up :-p ask another q. but for now i think ive sufficiently answered ur q :-D